# Impute factor values using dates

Tags: r, missing-data

I have a factor with missing values. I know that this factor value depends on the combination of a few dates.

I'm having some trouble getting this to work though. Seems both classes are tricky, especially `Date`.

For a simple example lets have 1 `Date` and 1 factor:

```
require(VIM)
toimpute          <- data.frame(mydates = seq(as.Date("1990-01-01"),as.Date("2000-01-01"),50),
                        imputeme = c(NA,NA,rep(c("a","b","c"),24)))
toimpute$imputeme <- as.factor(toimpute$imputeme)
```

It seems kNN won't go for it:

```
imputed <- kNN(toimpute,variable =  "imputeme")
```

> Error in `[.data.frame`(data.x, , i) : undefined columns selected

`mice` also doesn't like it. I thought `mice` was at least supposed to work with factors, though this message says it must be `numeric` (perhaps it allows `factor` dependent variables but only `numeric` for independent variables?):

```
imputed <- mice(toimpute)
```

> ```
>  iter imp variable
>   1   1  imputeme
> Error in FUN(newX[, i], ...) : 'x' must be numeric
> In addition: Warning messages:
> 1: In var(data[, j], na.rm = TRUE) :
>   Calling var(x) on a factor x is deprecated and will become an error.
>   Use something like 'all(duplicated(x)[-1L])' to test for a constant vector.
> 2: In FUN(newX[, i], ...) : NAs introduced by coercion
> ```

I guess if nothing else I can do a random forest model to predict the class of the observations with missing data, but if there's a way to do it with one of the more common missing value functions I'd like to know.

Comment: I think `aregImpute` works on factor variables. Check [this link](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/hmisc/docs/aregImpute)

Comment: @JosephWood That seems to work, add it as an answer if you like

Comment: I'm not sure about dates.  From the documentation I'm guessing they are automatically converted to factors.  Also, you can look into `transcan` from `Hmisc`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To handle imputation for factor variables, you can use [aregImpute](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/hmisc/docs/aregImpute) or [transcan](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/hmisc/docs/transcan) from the `Hmisc` package.

```
toimpute          <- data.frame(mydates = seq(as.Date("1990-01-01"),as.Date("2000-01-01"),50),
                                imputeme = c(NA,NA,rep(c("a","b","c"),24)))
toimpute$imputeme <- as.factor(toimpute$imputeme)
require(Hmisc)
imputed <- aregImpute(data=toimpute,mydates~imputeme)
table(is.na(imputed))

FALSE 
   19
```

From the documentation under Arguments (for `aregImpute`), it reads:

> formula
>   an S model formula. You can specify restrictions for transformations of variables. The function **automatically determines which variables are categorical** (i.e., factor, category, or character vectors). Binary variables are automatically restricted to be linear. Force linear transformations of continuous variables by enclosing variables by the identify function (I()). It is recommended that factor() or as.factor() do not appear in the formula but instead variables be converted to factors as needed and stored in the data frame. **That way imputations for factor variables (done using impute.transcan for example) will be correct.** Currently reformM does not handle variables that are enclosed in functions such as I().

Comment: Thanks, Joseph. When I get to work tomorrow I'll update this with the actual code.

Comment: @Hack-R, Great!! I was going to add a code example yesterday, but I was extremely busy. Also, not sure about the down-vote on the question as this seems like a very helpful question for the community, not to mention a well constructed question.